# Print Table In Bot emulator whose fields contain class object values

Tags: json, botframework, adaptive-cards

I want to print a table in Bot Emulator. The table contains values from a class object. What is the best way to do it?

I tried to do it using Adaptive card but I am stuck in printing variable values( class objects) as I cannot pass the objects parameter to my Json file made for adaptive card.

Comment: Please provide sample data that you would want to display in the card, as well as an explanation of how you would want the displayed data to look (a visual sketch of the layout would be ideal)

Answer (score 0):

Two-column tables can be included in Adaptive Cards as [fact sets](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/FactSet.html).

If you need more than two columns, just make each row in your table its own [column set](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ColumnSet.html).

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure your best approach might be using Adaptive cards, it shouldn't be that hard to load your card's properties before sending it as attachment as it's shown in MBF docs:

- .NET: [Add rich cards: Adaptive card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#adaptive-card)
- Node.js: [Send rich cards: Send an Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-an-adaptive-card)

Both links shows you how to send an adaptive card, using that, you may be able to create methods that parse your object to card's properties